# How can I add info to a object class?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

```
class Client{
String name;

Client(String name){
this.name=name;
}

Client (){
name=null;
}
}

class Cashier{

LinkedList <Client> cashierclients;


Cashier(LinkedList<Client> cashierclients){
this.cashierclients=cashierclients;
}
Cashier(){
//this.cashierclients=null;
}

}
class test{
public static void main(String args []){

LinkedList<Client> l=new LinkedList<Client>();

//i do some scans here to add the names of persons to the LinkedList l                   

Cashier [] cashier=new Cashier[numberofcashiers];

for(int i=0;i<numberofcashiers; i++){
    cashier[i]=new Cashier();
}
```

Now I want to add a client to cashier[0] i do this:

```
cashier[0].cashierclients.addLast(l.get(0));
```

everything works fine but when I want to print the size of cashier[1] it returns 1 but it should return 0 because I did not add any person to cashier[1]. Any ideas as to  what is  wrong?

```
// the error happens here
cashier[1].cashierclients.size();
```

Comment: If you never execute "Caixa(LinkedList<Client> cashierclients)" method then your program should be throwing a NullPointerException.

Comment: `cashier[0].cashierclients` and `cashier[1].cashierclients` should be null in your example, as @Eranda pointer out.

Comment: I did that, the program compiles and run fine... but when i print the size of cashier(1) which i didnt add anything to it....the output of size is 1 and it should be 0

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            cashier[i].cashierclients=empty;
        }
```

makes cashier[i].cashierclients point to the same object

so you can find

```
System.out.println(cashier[0].cashierclients == cashier[1].cashierclients);
```

equals to true

i think you shall change empty to new LinkedList()

that will fix the probelm

Comment: I posted the correct program. now if you run it you'll see what is the "error"

Comment: @CélioRodrigues What are you trying too achieve?

Comment: How can i do that? changing empty to new LinkedList()? 
I want to add a person to a the cashierclientes of cashier[0] and only to this one....but my program is adding the person to other cashier[i] which i dont want

Comment: so there is no point for empty to exist
you shall remove empty and use with new LinkedList()

Answer (score 0):

the program is working now and it shows the error in cashier[1] size that should return 0 instead of 1

```
import java.util.*;
class Client {
String name;

Client(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Client() {
    name = null;
}
}

class Cashier {

LinkedList<Client> cashierclients;


Cashier(LinkedList<Client> cashierclients) {
    this.cashierclients = cashierclients;
}

Cashier() {
//this.cashierclients=null;
}

}

public class test {
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    LinkedList<Client> l = new LinkedList<Client>();

// i created this LinkedList to solve the  nullpointerexception error

LinkedList<Client> empty =new LinkedList<Client>();

Client client1=new Client("Person1");
l.addLast(client1);

    Cashier[] cashier = new Cashier[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cashier[i] = new Cashier();
    }

// i did this to solve the  nullpointerexception error

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    cashier[i].cashierclients=empty;
}

cashier[0].cashierclients.addLast(l.get(0));

System.out.println(cashier[1].cashierclients.size());
//this should return zero
System.out.println(cashier[1].cashierclients.size());

}
}
```